# react - callbacks - 3 components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I have got 3 components:

-friendsPage which has list of friends and invitations to friends

-friendComponent which display friend info with possible actions (which are in the 3rd component)

-userFriendshipActionComponent - which display buttons with possible actions (like add to friends list, remove from friends, etc)

i use userFriendshipActionComponent in multiple places

the problem is:

when i use the button from the 3rd component, i want to convey to 1st info that friend has been added or removed from list, so the 1st component will refresh list of friends, or will refresh invitations list

so firsty, the methods in friends Page

```
callBack(action:string){
    if(action === 'invitations'){
        this.getInvitations();
    }
    else if(action === 'friends'){
        this.getFriends();
    }
    else{
        this.getInvitations();
        this.getFriends();
    }
}

  const friendsList = this.state.friends.map(x=>{
        return (
        <div key={x.id} style={userStyle}>
        <FriendComponent user={x}></FriendComponent>
        </div>)
    })

    const invitationsList = this.state.invitations.map(x=>{
        return (
            <div key={x.id} style={userStyle}>
            <FriendComponent user={x} callBack={this.callBack} />
            </div>)
    })



    return(
    <div className="Friends">
        <h3>Friends</h3>
        {friendsList}
        <h3>Invitations to friends</h3>
        {invitationsList}
    </div>
    )
```

as you can see i convey the callbackfunction to friendComponent by props

```
 <FriendComponent user={x} callBack={this.callBack} />
```

next in friendComponent

```
 callBack = (action) =>{
        console.log("friendComponent callBack");
        if(this.props.callBack!==null && this.props.callBack!==undefined)
        {
            if(action === 'removeFriend'){
                this.props.callBack('friends');
            }
            else{
                this.props.callBack();
            } 
        }
    }


    render(){

        return (
            <>

        <UserComponent user={this.props.user} />
        <UserFriendshipActionComponent userId={this.props.user.id ?? 0} callBack={this.callBack} />
        </>
        )
    }
```

I convey second callback function to child component UserFriendshipActionComponent .

In the end in UserFriendshipActionComponent, on button click i use some for example this function

```
acceptFriendship = (userId:number)=>{

        this.friendshipService.AcceptFriendship(userId);
        this.setState({
            friendshipStatus:'friends'
        })
        if(this.props.callBack !== null && this.props.callBack!==undefined)
            this.props.callBack("addFriend");
    }
```

problem is in the friendsPage

> × TypeError: this.getInvitations is not a function callBack
>   C:/repo/priv/react/clr/RandevouReact/src/pages/FriendsPage.tsx:54   51
>   |         this.getFriends();   52 |     }   53 |     else{
>
> > 54 |         this.getInvitations();   55 |         this.getFriends();   56 |     }   57 | }

how to fix it? 
what is wrogn with this piece of code?

if it is matter, getInvitations functions call api in the backend, and after receiving data it set state with friendsList or invitationsList or in both

Answer (score 0):

sorry for problem, i forgot that  i have to bind method from first component (friendscomponent) because i have lost "this" in third component, so it tried to call this.getInvitations from the 3rd component instead of 1st component

```
 const friendsList = this.state.friends.map(x=>{
        return (
        <div key={x.id} style={userStyle}>
        <FriendComponent user={x} callBack={this.callBack.bind(this)}></FriendComponent>
        </div>)
    })

    const invitationsList = this.state.invitations.map(x=>{
        return (
            <div key={x.id} style={userStyle}>
            <FriendComponent user={x} callBack={this.callBack.bind(this)} />
            </div>)
    })
```